# how to create a form builder element for mongoid if the type is a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a class called Case, it has a field called data, which is of type Hash.  data has multiple levels:

```
class Case
     include Mongoid::Document

     field :data, type: Hash
...
end
```

Suppose a case's data is a plain old hash of data, such as:

```
"data": {"DOB": "10/19/1990",..
```

And further, suppose it has multiple levels:

```
"data": {"DOB": "10/19/1990",.., "preferences": {"best time to call": "9:00am"...
```

How can I set, say, a text input, to let me set a sub-attribute?  This does not work:

```
<%= f.text_field :data["preferences"]["best time to call"]
```

Hopefully the above code illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.  The challenge is that the nested attributes are not full blown models, they're just hash nodes, so the usual fields_for doesn't work.

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Answer (score 0):

You should try writing your form element helper as:

```
<%= f.text_field 'data[preferences][best time to call]'
```